# I have some problems from the complicated nature of Instant Article of STEP2

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I'm so confused about the instant articles. I use Wordpress to connect with instant articles but it told me that on Step2 (Submitted for review).

It couldn't review my Instant Articles at this time. Some possible reasons for this include the inability to access the mobile web versions of my articles (Facebook compares the mobile web version to the Instant Article to make sure all content has been included) or the font in my Instant Article not rendering correctly.As a first step, make sure that the mobile web versions load correctly before resubmitting. Please refer to the below reviewer notes for more specific information.

Moreover, I use Newspaper theme of Wordpress and already talked with the support of Facebook, They suggest me to ask here. I think, the system of Facebook is error.So, how to fix it ??

I hope you reply me soonest, Thanks!

Comment: https://scontent.fbkk9-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/26938008_10211429111191397_281611936_o.jpg?oh=a60f453ad1f3728ad9f216861fd5b6e4&oe=5A616C63

Comment: https://scontent.fbkk9-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/26857328_10211429112471429_2014447248_n.jpg?oh=96848ccf2f7bd41efb73519d47448dab&oe=5A616B03

Answer (score 0):

The review process expects your m-web version of your article to have public/accessible URLs.

Make sure you have your articles published on Wordpress and that they are available publicly on the same canonical URL as you inform on your Instant Articles Markup.